# Maintain Facet count after faceting

Tags: solr, content-search, search-facet

I'm using `Sitecore 9.3` and `Solr 8.1.1`. I'm developing a search filter using `Sitecore Content Search API`, with the behavior of keeping the facet count the same even after selecting options.

For example, if the filter have these options :

- Option 1 , count = 11
- Option 2 , count = 20
- Option 3 , count = 8

If I select **Option 1**, other options' count will change according to this selection.

I don't want that, I want to maintain the count as it is in the same Solr query.
At the same time, I have multiple filters, so I want to keep the count for only the options in the selected filter, while other filters count can be changed.

Comment: Looks like you need to separate Solr call for facets count and skip filters while getting facets count

Comment: @MarekMusielak
 I agree with you, but I have multiple filters, and I need to keep the count for only the options in the selected one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr provides [Tagging and Excluding Filters](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_0/faceting.html#tagging-and-excluding-filters) functionality to support facets for multi-select fields. It allows to tag a part of filter query and then exclude the tagged part when counting facets for a specific field.

Sitecore Content Search provider currently does not support `tag` and `ex` parameters and does not have any Linq extension methods for passing them to Solr.

There is a good example of how to prepare and apply these parameters by extending Sitecore Content Search query with SolrNet QueryOptions in the question [Sitecore Solr multiple filter tagging / excluding](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/26368/sitecore-solr-multiple-filter-tagging-excluding).

However, if you want to solve this by using only out-of-the-box Content Search API, be prepared to perform N+1 requests to Solr (where N is the number of multi-select filters with at least one option selected):

1. Request with all filters applied to get valid results.
2. Request without conditions from the first multi-select filter to get facets for this filter options.
3. Request without conditions from the second multi-select filter, and so on until you process all multi-select filters.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this is really helpful